# LINQ: take a sequence of elements from a collection

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a collection of objects and need to take batches of 100 objects and do some work with them until there are no objects left to process.

Instead of looping through each item and grabbing 100 elements then the next hundred etc is there a nicer way of doing it with linq?

Many thanks

Comment: LukeH's answer is much better, please accept and use it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
static void test(IEnumerable<object> objects)
{
    while (objects.Any())
    {
        foreach (object o in objects.Take(100))
        {
        }
        objects = objects.Skip(100); 
    }
}
```

:)

Comment: Be careful if using this approach with Entity Framework. The SQL it generates will have an extra sub query on each iteration. If there are more than 50 batches, the query fails.

Answer (score 12):

```
int batchSize = 100;
var batched = yourCollection.Select((x, i) => new { Val = x, Idx = i })
                            .GroupBy(x => x.Idx / batchSize,
                                     (k, g) => g.Select(x => x.Val));

// and then to demonstrate...
foreach (var batch in batched)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Processing batch...");

    foreach (var item in batch)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Processing item: " + item);
    }
}
```

Comment: it is very inefficient. GroupBy is expensive operation

Comment: @Andrey: I suggest that you benchmark your own answer against the `GroupBy` version before you make any claims about inefficiency. You might be surprised by the results.

Comment: you are right, your method is more performant (more then 10x)!

Comment: @Andrey: There are definitely more performant ways than `GroupBy` to do this. The obvious technique would be looping as the OP mentions in the question, or maybe something like Lee's or Foole's answers. I suggested `GroupBy` because it's succinct and doesn't need any extra helper code, not because it's the most efficient way to do this.

Comment: yes, there are more efficient code, but i was surprised to see that `GroupBy` is faster

Comment: Just came across this looking to refactor some 'loop until this amount then start a new row'.  Very nice, would be a classic extension method.

Answer (score 3):

This will partition the list into a list of lists of however many items you specify.

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Partition<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int size)
{
    int i = 0;
    List<T> list = new List<T>(size);
    foreach (T item in source)
    {
        list.Add(item);
        if (++i == size)
        {
            yield return list;
            list = new List<T>(size);
            i = 0;
        }
    }
    if (list.Count > 0)
        yield return list;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think linq is really suitable for this sort of processing - it is mainly useful for performing operations on whole sequences rather than splitting or modifying them. I would do this by accessing the underlying `IEnumerator<T>` since any method using `Take` and `Skip` are going to be quite inefficient.

```
public static void Batch<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, int batchSize, Action<IEnumerable<T>> batchAction)
{
    if (batchSize < 1) throw new ArgumentException();

    List<T> buffer = new List<T>();
    using (var enumerator = (items ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>()).GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            buffer.Add(enumerator.Current);
            if (buffer.Count == batchSize)
            {
                batchAction(buffer);
                buffer.Clear();
            }
        }

        //execute for remaining items
        if (buffer.Count > 0)
        {
            batchAction(buffer);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var batchSize = 100;
for (var i = 0; i < Math.Ceiling(yourCollection.Count() / (decimal)batchSize); i++)
{
    var batch = yourCollection
        .Skip(i*batchSize)
        .Take(batchSize);

    // Do something with batch
}
```